# Use django from InteractiveConsole

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice
```

I am using django(1.11) document to make polls app now i editing (polls/models) as according to document this shows me error.

My polls/models is something is wrong with me.plz Help!!

```
    Question.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\mysite\polls\models.py", line 16, in __str__
    return self.question
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'question'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the `__str__` of `Question` model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text
    #                 ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

as Bear Brown answered you, the error is a type on your function `__str__`, his suggestion will fix the problem, but I would reconsider the field's name in `Question`.

The proper field name should be `text` only and not `question_text` because the field is already in the domain of the `Question`.

Imagine this code

```
for question in Question.objects.all():
    print(question.question_text)
```

As you can see the `question` as prefix of `text` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Question.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\mysite\polls\models.py", line 16, in __str__
    return self.text
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: if you changed the attribute, you must run also the migration or the models will not reflect the database situation: `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `python manage.py migrate`